# Mongoose.js schema description issue (array vs object)

Tags: node.js

I need to store some user dictionaries (sets of words, and I need to store it as user property) and each dictionary has actually only one property: language.

So I can describe that property like that:

```
dictionaries:[{language: 'string', words: [.. word entry schema desc..]
    }]
```

and store dictionaries like that:

```
dictionaries: [
   {language: en, words: [.. words of English dictionary..]},
   {language: es, words: [.. words of Spanish dictionary..]}
]
```

But actually I could store the dictionaries in "less nested" way: not array abut object:

```
dictionaries: {
   en: [.. words of English dictionary..],
   es: [.. words of Spanish dictionary..]
}
```

But I don't see a way to describe such object with mongoose schema. So the question is what is the best (more reasonable in terms of storage and querying) option to go with considering I use mongoose.

Comment: You can use mixed object type and make sure mixed schema accept any type of key

Comment: Yes, but thus I can not use schema description. I would go with first for the sake of structure, I just worry that if that exessive complexity make sense.

Comment: I feel there is no major complexity using on "First" instead of second, choosing first one is more appreciated.

Comment: In terms of selecting it's (coffeescript): `@dictionaries.en` vs `return d for d in @dictionaries when d.language is 'en'` or `@dictionaries.filter (d) -> d.language is 'en'`. Or am I missing something? I would really like to see dictionaries in mongoose :/